# Does anyone know of any cheap and easy True Client performance test solutions?

Tags: firebug, selenium-ide, performance-testing

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to include an element of true client testing in my load tests. Due to budget limitations Loadrunner is totally out of the question however I have come up with an interim solution as follows:

- Apply load to application under test using Facilita (as per current load tests)
- Using Selenium IDE automate playback of browser based tests, pacing in line with the Facilita load
- Log results from Firebug Netmonitor, automatically exporting as HAR files

There are a fair few limitations to this method, however for my purposes its not bad. My main problem is that analysis of results is a bit of a pain this way as I have to group the outputs from each test, open them with an HAR viewer then manually add response times to a spreadsheet.

So I guess my questions are as follows:

1. Is there an easier, more versatile way of doing this on a (very) limited budget?
2. If not, is there a better way of extracting response times from Firebug?

I've tried converting the HAR files to csv but haven't been able to split up the columns, making it just as time consuming to work through my data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that HP now offer an unlimited free version of Loadrunner upto 50 virtual users, which is more than sufficient for my needs.

http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/try-now.html

So my solution is now to create load with Facilita Eggplant and add HP Loadrunner TruClient as an extra layer to the test.

Answer (score 0):

TrueClient=LoadRunner

GUI Virtual User, running an automated functional testing tool as the end user agent for performance testing is state of the art as of 1992/3.  You will be shifting your costs to your test infrastructure.   Even so, if you want to head down this path is

- LoadRunner/QTP
- Borland SilkPerformer/SilkTest
- IBM Rational Performance Tester/Rational Functional Tester
- Selenium/Browsermob